# Internet speed through ethernet connections

Tags: wireless-networking, powerline-networking

connecting multiple gaming consoles to my router via wifi clearly affects the speed per device, does the same thing happen if I had them all connected via Ethernet cable and powerline network?

Comment: We need more details of the hardware used for wireless and powerline network. Its all hinging on bandwidth for each technology you are using, no way we can answer without more details.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.howtogeek.com/217463/wi-fi-vs.-ethernet-how-much-better-is-a-wired-connection/

The short answer is a wired connection might be better.  The powerline adapters aren't going to be much better than wireless, but wireless is affected by latency and interference.  And, in either case, you will be bottlenecked by your internet connection itself.  I stream constantly on wifi, not to mention several other wireless devices connected at same time and have little issues.  But if I were trying to game and stream on more than one device at the same time, over wifi, I might notice the difference.  You really are better off with a wired, direct connection for streaming or gaming, but a good wifi connection is just as good.

So, bottom line: wired might be better for you if you are having issues.  But, as Frank says, NAT can be an issue.  But I wouldn't bother with powerline.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes, since in WiFi the air is shared by all the users, as opposed to Ethernet cables. The other case might be the router itself, check the specifications - maybe there you will find some data regarding the speed difference.

Comment: Note that many modern consoles will not work correctly if there is more than one of them per home, due to NAT requirements. If you are not trying to play online, then its probably fine, there will be feature limitations.

Comment: I believe I have a c1000z router from centurylink, and am thinking of purchasing Actiontec - 500 Mbps Powerline Home Theater Network Adapter Kit (powerline network adapter). I am paying for 40mbps. I guess my question is can I get top speed from router by using direct connection via Ethernet cable (on powerline device). hope it makes sense sorry and thanks for helping

Comment: @eric Please edit your question to add the info from your comment.